# как добавить в БД

Tags: php, база-данных

как добавить данные из $myarr в бд, чтобы при этом было читабельно так же как при выводе через foreach

```
$my_array=array("1"=>"7",
"2"=>"6",
"3"=>"3",
"4"=>"4",
"5"=>"1");

shuffle($my_array);

foreach($my_array as $myarr)
{
echo $myarr;
}




         $query = "UPDATE users SET Blnwin=".$myarr." WHERE id=".$id."";
         $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1):

спасибо, сделал так

```
 $a1 = array("1","2","3","4","5");
 shuffle($a1);
 $a2 = implode("",$a1)."";
 echo $a2;
```